# Non-unique multicolumn foreign key

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, constraint

I have a "comments" table that models a conversation on a topic, like this:

```
id serial  
topic_id integer  
parent_comment_id integer
body text
```

So, every comment has a reference to its topic AND eventually its parent comment (if it's not the first comment on the topic).
I'd like to add a constraint that would prevent adding rows having mismatched topic/parent (for example by referencing a topic that *doesn't* have the required comment, or conversely a comment that references the wrong topic).
Is this possible? Is a trigger required?

(For the record, I tried

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD FOREIGN KEY (parent_comment_id, topic_id)
                 REFERENCES comments (id, topic_id)
```

but it complains that `there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "comments"`)

Comment: does a primary key exist on the 'comments' table?

Comment: Yes sorry, it's the id

Comment: Try **create unique index how_you_want_to_name_this_index on comments (id, topic_id);** before issuing the alter table command adding the foreign key.

Comment: Or just add the line **unique (id, topic_id),** in your "create table"-command for comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add super-key (unique index/constraint) on both (id,topic_id). This gives you the  "target" uniqueness to create your foreign key. This acts like a CHECK constraint in this case.

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD 
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_comment_id, topic_id) REFERENCES comments (id, topic_id)
```

Note: id remains as primary key to preserve the model. Even if id is serial, it's would be wrong from a modelling perspective to change the PK to (id,topic_id)

Comment: That is technically correct, but logically this is no new constraint. Given the primary key on id, it is always fulfilled. I.e. it is just a disabilities of the implementation of the DBMS.

Comment: @bernd_k: this is why I said "super key". It also decouples actual PK from the superkey/FK.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD FOREIGN KEY (parent_comment_id, topic_id)
    REFERENCES comments (id)
```

If you want this to work:

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD FOREIGN KEY (parent_comment_id, topic_id)
    REFERENCES comments (id, topic_id)
```

Then I believe you need to change your PK to be on both the id and topic_id columns.

Also, I think this link helps explain what you need: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-constraints.html

Comment: The first command gives me `number of referencing and referenced columns for foreign key disagree` :/ I think the problem with my command is that there could be multiple rows with matching parent + topic

Comment: OK, can you alter the primary key to have two columns? then your original command should work, i believe.